# How can i access my swagger-ui when using spring security

Tags: java, spring-security, swagger

I'm trying to get access to my swagger-ui but spring security keeps blocking it. How do I prevent this ?

This is the swagger configuration

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig  {

    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.safariwebstore008"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

}
```

This is the webSecurity configuration

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register","/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers().hasAnyRole()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In `protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)` do what you did with `"/register"` endpoint.